# Adding new members to C++ structure and backwards compatibility

Tags: c++, c, backwards-compatibility

I have a struct which is used by others somewhere, they rely on `sizeof(struct S)` as well. Below is my struct,

```
struct S{
   int  aVar1;
   void *ptr1;
}
```

In future, I might add new members to it(Not sure right now) like..

```
struct S{
   int  aVar1;
   void *ptr1;
   int aVar2;
   void *ptr2;
}
```

I know this breaks the backward compatibility with the users who rely on `sizeof`.

To avoid this I plan to add some dummy pointers to struct which can be used in future.

```
struct S{
   int  aVar1;
   void *ptr1;
   void *dummyptr1;
   void *dummyptr2;
   void *dummyptr3;
   void *dummyptr4;
   void *dummyptr5;
   void *dummyptr6;
 }
```

Any better solution please to maintain backward compatibility ?

Comment: a better solution would be not to expect that the size of the struct never changes when in reality it does change

Comment: What information do clients think they get from `sizeof(struct S)`?

Comment: In which sense do you want to keep compatibility? Could you give an example where compatibility becomes important? You should be aware of that strictly speaking according to the standard none of the above definitions of `S` are compatible (so you must take into account the toolchain/platform specifics).

Comment: btw in general you have little control over what the actual size of a struct is (padding etc.) even if you dont change anything on it

Comment: Couldn't you could create a new struct where the old one is a member. Of course if you keep doing this this becomes impossible to maintain.

Comment: You can add an array of pointers and add the pointers there when you need a new one. But I think tobi303 is right.

Comment: Why are they relying on sizeof struct? Are the actually relying on the ABI not chaning? Are they not recompiling (and you are writing a library)? Are you passing a message? Would a factory work? Serialise/desreialise with a version number? It depends...

Comment: Users who use `sizeof` won't have a problem because `sizeof` will correctly provide the new size. All they have to do is recompile to link with your new version.

Comment: Would a pimpl be feasible? Hide the new members behind an opaque pointer, similar to [Qt's d-pointer]( http://wiki.qt.io/D-Pointer)

Comment: Code that uses  `sizeof(struct S)` is _good_.  Relaying on that `sizeof(struct S)` will be the same value per each and future compilations is _bad_.

Answer (score 5):

Don't do this.

It's not even safe to add new members to the structure in the hope that the *existing* members keep their current padding arrangements. Neither the C nor C++ standards make any guarantees in this respect.

The only safe approach is to build a new structure from scratch and add new API functions.

Comment: However in C++ you're guaranteed to keep the layout if you add members via inheritance.

Comment: @skyking Yes that is true.

Comment: This is a bit extreme... Yes, the C standard makes no guarantee, but we don't always target "just" the standard, but specific platforms, and virtually any platform I know of provide explicit ABI guarantees that make binary compatibility possible and routinely done.

Comment: The concepts here might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Object_Request_Broker_Architecture

Comment: @MatteoItalia Yes, but for that you/we need to know what platform/toolchain you're targeting, otherwise you can only rely on what the standard prescribes. Note that it's often a bad idea to target a specific platform/toolchain if you don't actually need to - I'd suggest that you try to find a portable solution before you resign to using a platform/toolchain specific solution. Often that's possible and not too hard.

Answer (score 2):

Afaik, the C way of doing it is to use extensions, like so:

```
struct A{
  int data;
  void* extension;
};
```

Then, when needed you add the extension and link it with the original `A` using extension pointer.

```
struct A_ext1{
  int ext_data;
  void* extension;
};

A a;
A_ext1 a_ext1;
a.extension = &a_ext1;
```

and so on... This will create a nasty "layered" structure of structs. This ensures that your original structure will never change, so clients that use old interface will stay compatible after it changes without the need to recompile.

The important thing here is to keep track of the version of your interface - each new extension is the new version. Ten your clients need to be aware of the version they support, so they only know and support the extensions only up to the version they know. Also you need to make sure not to pass ownership of such struct to the clients. They do not know how many layers of extensions there might be, so they will not be able to properly destroy the whole thing.

Of course you could also try C++ approach and just use inheritance, creating new versions of struct that inherit from the old one. I'm not sure about implications of the later approach, but it should also work.

Answer (score 1):

You could write a new structure derived from old structure if it is c++. By doing this, you may use new structure in old functions and have new functions for new structure as well.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is specifically solved using the "Decorator Pattern". It simply allows you to extend the functionality of an existing class (a struct in your case) without changing its structure, using composition. You'll simply have to create a new struct (or class) with that old struct as a member in your new struct. Then you'll add new functionality to this new struct as you desire. More info [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/decorator_pattern.htm).